# How do you format the -I option with hg diff?

Tags: mercurial

New to using Mercurial.

I've got a workspace in a Jenkins installation and I want to diff, commit and push only two of the changed files. the result of `hg st` looks like this:

```
M version/build_driver.sh
M version/client_version.txt
M version/server_version.txt
M version/update_client.sh
M version/update_server.sh
```

I only want to diff, commit, and checkin the files

```
M version/client_version.txt
M version/server_version.txt
```

to my mercurial source code repository. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `hg diff`, either give the `-I` option multiple times:

```
hg diff -I version/client_version.txt -I version/server_version.txt
```

or use shell glob syntax:

```
hg diff -I 'version/{server,client}_version.txt'
```

For `hg commit`, either use the same syntax or just list the files on the command line without a `-I`:

```
hg commit version/{server,client}_version.txt
```

And `hg push` doesn't need a filename argument.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, it won't let me up-vote since I'm new to the forum.